# language c++, Error invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++

I find the error that is in the title, this in my program that is a static queue with all its methods or functions, this error is in the following function.

```
void Cola::queve(TIPO_DATO datos){
if(cola1.vacia()){
    final = (final+1)%TAM;
    datos[final] = datos;
}else{
    cout<<"No hay espacios en la cola"<<endl;
}
}
```

Anyway I leave the rest of the code in case something, I hope your answers thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define TAM 10
#define TIPO_DATO int

void menu();

class Cola{
private:
    TIPO_DATO  datos[TAM];
    int frente;
    int final;
public:
    void inicializa();
    bool vacia();
    bool llena();
    TIPO_DATO front();
    void queve(TIPO_DATO datos);
    void deque();
    void imprimir();
    void anular();
 };

 int main(){

 menu();
 return 0;
 }

 Cola cola1;

 void menu(){
 int opc;
 int a;

 cola1.inicializa();
 cout<<"\t \t ***** MENU PRINCIPAL *****"<<endl;
 cout<<"Selecciona la opcion deseeada"<<endl;
 cout<<"1. Vacia"<<endl;
 cout<<"2. Llena"<<endl;
 cout<<"3. Front"<<endl;
 cout<<"4. Encolar"<<endl;
 cout<<"5. Deseencolar"<<endl;
 cout<<"6. Imprimir"<<endl;
 cout<<"7. Anular"<<endl;
 cout<<"8. Salir"<<endl;
 cin>>opc;
 cout<<endl;
 switch(opc){
    case 1: cola1.vacia();
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
    case 3: cout<<"cola1.front()"<<endl;
    break;
    case 4:
    break;
    case 5:
    break;
    case 6:
    break;
    case 7: cola1.anular();
    break;
    case 8:
    break;  
  }

}

//Prototipos de la cola

void Cola::inicializa(){
frente = 0;
final = TAM-1;
}

bool Cola::vacia(){
if(frente == 0 && final == TAM-1){
    return true;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"La cola se encuentra vacia"<<endl;
}else{
    return false;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"La cola no esta vacia"<<endl;
}
system("PAUSE");
menu();
}

bool Cola::llena(){

}

void Cola::queve(TIPO_DATO datos){
if(cola1.vacia()){
    final = (final+1)%TAM;
    datos[final] = datos;
}else{
    cout<<"No hay espacios en la cola"<<endl;
}
}

void Cola::deque(){

}

TIPO_DATO Cola::front(){
if(cola1.vacia()){
    return datos[frente];
}
else{
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
}
}

void Cola::imprimir(){

}

void Cola::anular(){
frente = 0;
final = TAM-1;

}
```

Comment: Don't use the same name for an argument as for a member variable. You're just lucky that it's a compilation error in this case.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to use plural names for singular things ("dato"/"datos"); nothing after a `return` ever gets executed (see `vacia`); the queue should not be concerned with pausing or the menu (also `vacia`); and a function that is supposed to return a value should always return a value (see `front` and `llena`).

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.  Your compiler could have told you that you made this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function parameter `datos` hides the members variable of the same name,
either

- use different name:

  ```
  void Cola::queve(int new_datos){
      if(cola1.vacia()){
          final = (final+1)%TAM;
          datos[final] = new_datos;
      }else{
          cout<<"No hay espacios en la cola"<<endl;
      }
  }
  ```
- or use `this->` for the hidden member variable:

  ```
  void Cola::queve(int datos){
      if(cola1.vacia()){
          final = (final+1)%TAM;
          this->datos[final] = datos;
      }else{
          cout<<"No hay espacios en la cola"<<endl;
      }
  }
  ```